# How to use sibling combinator with :valid pseudoclass in IE?

Tags: css, validation, css-selectors, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I've stumbled across some odd behavior in IE 10 and 11.  The adjacent sibling CSS combinator works. (`+`)  The `:valid` and `:invalid` pseudo classes work.  But when you put them together, they get weird.

Take this html

```
<input required>
<p class="message">message</p>
```

styled with this css

```
input:valid { border: solid green 1px; }
input:invalid { border: solid red 1px; }

input:valid + .message { background-color: green; }
input:invalid + .message { background-color: red; }
```

When there is no text in the input, it correctly has a red border.  The color of the following message should always match.  However, you have to perform a page zoom to get the colors to synchronize.  Note that merely resizing the viewport is not enough.  Is this a bug?  Is there a workaround?

[Here's a demo.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGKmi)

Comment: Ah yes, the classic IE/Chrome "I cannot repaint things properly" bug.

Comment: For the record, resizing the preview pane or the browser window does trigger a repaint for me in IE11 on Windows 7. Also, no issues on Chrome with this particular scenario, but Chrome has repainting issues of its own that are comparable to IE's.

Answer (score 1):

As BoltClock said in its comment, it's a repaint bug.

You can force a repainting by toggling the `display` css to `none` and back to `block` in the `.message` element.

Example:

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.message').css('display','none').css('display', '');
});
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but I'd like to avoid spurious event handlers in browsers that actually handle it correctly to begin with.  Do you know a way to detect whether this is needed?

Comment: Sorry, But I don't know another way to fix this.

Comment: To detect if it's a IE10/IE11 you could use conditional comments for the HTML element. For more details http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Comment: @João Mosmann: Conditional comments don't work in IE10 and later.